# returning a string for an amount with a Dollar sign and no commas - Java

Tags: java, string, methods

How do I return a string for a specified amount with a `$` sign and no commas? For example, the amount 10538 cents becomes the string `$105.38`.

Comment: is this `amount` a String, float, int ...?

Comment: it is an int. @jonk I have tried multiple ways but could not find a solution yet.

Comment: Try with div and modulo operators to get `105` and `38`. Rest is simple concatenation.

Comment: You should also explain how to handle special cases like `0`. Do you want `$0.0` or `$0.00`, or maybe `$0`?

Comment: If it is below or equal to zero it will throw a new IllegalArgumentException. @Pshemo

Comment: That requirement should be part of your question. Please [edit] it to include all necessary informations to provide proper answer.

Comment: This is what I got so far:         
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        double dollars = amount / 100.0;

        return nf.format(dollars);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just divide the amount by 100, format it to 2 decimal places, and prepend a '$':

```
public static String toDollarStr(int amountInCents) {
    return String.format("$%.2f", (float)amountInCents/100);
}
```

If you want to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the value is equal to or less than zero as stated in your comment (which I'm not sure why would be desired), just add an if statement:

```
public static String toDollarStr(int amountInCents) {
    if (amountInCents <= 0)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return String.format("$%.2f", (float)amountInCents/100);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you have a comma being outputted this will be due to locale, and can be solved by explicitly specifying a locale that won't do this, e.g. US:

```
return String.format(Locale.US, "$%.2f", (float)amountInCents/100);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @yonk unfortunately the output contains a comma. For example 1999 the output is 19,99. Maybe there are regional differences. I am from Germany.

Comment: the output of this function cannot possibly contain a comma... is the amount an int or a String with comma?

Comment: it is an int with comma

Comment: I'm not understanding you I'm afraid... do you mean the input is `String amount = "1,000"` or `int amount = 1000` ?

Comment: here's a [demo](https://ideone.com/SThVRu) of an example usage which might help clear things up

Answer (score 0):

If last 2 digits are always cents:

```
str = "$" + str.substring(0,str.length()-2) +"."+str.substring(str.length()-2,str.length());
```